# Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider on Android Studio

Tags: android

It crash my app were it says "Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped" and I don't have any idea how to fix this thing I really need help.

**This is what i saw in logcat:**

```
04-30 06:52:50.214 21423-21423/com.parse.starter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.parse.starter, PID: 21423
                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.parse.starter-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/com.parse.starter-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5049)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4620)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4553)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:160)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1390)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5330)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.parse.starter-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/com.parse.starter-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5034)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4620) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4553) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:160) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1390) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5330) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**And this is the build.gradle file**

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 22
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"

    minSdkVersion = 19
    targetSdkVersion = 23
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

**The Manifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.parse.starter">
    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name=".StarterApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

**The Source Code**

```
package com.parse.starter;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;


public class StarterApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .applicationId("xxxxxx")
            .clientKey("xxxxxx")
            .server("xxxxx")
            .build()
    );

    ParseObject object = new ParseObject("ExampleObject");
    object.put("myNumber", "123");
    object.put("myString", "gerard");

    object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback () {
      @Override
      public void done(ParseException ex) {
        if (ex == null) {
          Log.i("Parse Result", "Successful!");
        } else {
          Log.i("Parse Result", "Failed" + ex.toString());
        }
      }
    });


    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();

    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

  }
}
```

Kindly help me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Change this on your build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
```

for this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1'
```